# How Mix Overlay Node actually works

Tags: shaders

I would like to know what is the math behind The Mix Overlay Node.

For example, let`s suppose I have
Color 1: 123.255.255
Color 2: 147.124.254

what`s gonna be the final color if I use mix Overlay?
[image]

And what is the influence of Fac

Comment: The fac controls how much the color mixes with one or the other. With it set to 0 it will simply be the first color you chose, and it would be completely blue if its 1. You can use a texture to control specific spots to be different mixes.

Comment: There is no reason that this shouldn't be the same as in any other software, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Overlay